# Calculating area of Circle using Rest API service in Spring boot

Tags: algorithm, spring-boot, rest

I was trying to calculate areas and perimeters of figures,such as: circle,triangle,rectangle using rest api Spring boot.However,as I am new to programming I am confused about how to do it step by step by plan.Anyone please share your experiance with me about steps of calculating areas of figures in rest api service.

Comment: But you know how to do this with math?

Comment: Yes it is easy  calculation in math

Comment: So what's your question exactly? Do you wan to know how to calculate with Java then have a look at the java.math package. Or do you want to know how to create REST services with Spring Boot then read the documentation. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/